# Is it possible to get (set) multiple text attributes in a single spreadsheet cell programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Since the introduction of the new spreadsheet version one can change text attributes inside a single cell (or merged cells) manually like in this example :

(left = raw text, right = formatted text, easier to read)

[image]

I don't see any way to achieve that by script... I don't see any issue nor feature request in the issue tracker either.

Is that possible ?

Every method I try to get the text attributes only returns a single value so I'm afraid I just can't do it... but who knows ?

Comment: From looking at the reference I don't think this is possible as all range methods return more ranges or other native types. You'd expect it to return something like a Text object such as in the docs class.

Comment: Welcome back, buddy! Long time, no post! No surprise... you start with an impossible task.

Comment: Nope... raise the feature request, so it can be summarily ignored.

Comment: haha ... thx, will do.

Comment: Did you raise the issue? If this question had an answer with that info, we could dup [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34799073/1677912) to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2016, when this answer was originally posted, in Google Sheets was not possible to programatically apply formatting to cell content parts.

<s>Please star the</s> The following feature request on the Google Apps Scripts issues and feature requests official site is now fixed.

[Issue 6000:    Handle parts of cell content programmatically](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6000)

According to [the release notes of January 22, 2019](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#january_22_2019) Google Apps Script was updated to include new classes and methods to handle cell content formatting like `RichTextValue`.