# Bolding a specific text in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm planning for a school event and I have 2 sheets. One which contains a list of speakers and their topics, the other is the event agenda. I've written a script to grab data from the list of speakers sheet to print onto the sheet which contains the agenda. This is an example of the text in one of the cells

```
Topic: How To Hold The Door

Speaker: Kristian Nairn
```

Is there a way for Google Apps script to bold only the Topic while leaving the formatting for the Speaker? I've been thinking of ways to bold it while it's in String format or bold it when printing but still no solution.

Comment: The only way to do it would  be if those 2 strings were in separate cells, so if they are side by side you can easily do conditional formatting

Answer (score 1):

From my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37700736/1595451) to [Is it possible to get (set) multiple text attributes in a single spreadsheet cell programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721449/is-it-possible-to-get-set-multiple-text-attributes-in-a-single-spreadsheet-cel/)

> At this time in Google Sheets is not possible to programatically apply
>   formatting to cell content parts.
>
> Please star the following feature request on the Google Apps Scripts
>   issues and feature requests officil site:   [Issue 6000:  Handle parts
>   of cell content
>   programmatically](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6000)